# what action cause select function timeout while it detect socket's write status.

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, solaris, solaris-10

my application running in solaris 10.
It is a C/S model.
Client and Server programs in the same server.
I have set the client program 's socket send buffer is 49512 and TCP_NODELAY option.
select's timeout interval is 1s.
while my client running, i found if net statics is very large, select will be timeout,
I want to know what action maybe cause socket not write ready.
Send buffer is full? or others?

Comment: You should illustrate what you mean by adding some code

Comment: have you tried the appropriate man-pages (man -s C3 select)?

Comment: if I understend well you use select for writing to the socket? If yes why u just don't use normal send? It will be useful to paste some pseudocode to better understand your application.

Answer (score 1):

You are right: select() times out because the send buffer is full.

Because the TCP protocol guarantees delivery, data will not be removed from the send buffer until the sender *knows* it has safely landed in the receive buffer on the other end of the socket.

This means the send buffer fills up e.g. when the receiving end has a full receive buffer, or when sent packets (or ACKs from the receiver) are lost on the network.

Even when select() does *not* time out, the send buffer may be *almost* full, and then your write() call will not write all of your data to the buffer. Always check the return value of your write() or send() call - this gives the number of bytes actually written